# Simple phpinfo script causes 403 forbidden why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

A simple phpinfo.php script would generate two 403 forbidden error. The website itself has no such error at all. Is there something wrong with my .htaccess? I had ajax call with such 403 errors as well.

[image]

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

`FilesMatch` accepts a regex and in regex dot means any character. To match literal dot you should escape it.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
   Order Allow,Deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: It's not that. I start to think this is a apache bug. I have another website having this problem too. And even I remove .htaccess, same. It only appear for phpinfo. The website itself has not such error at all.

Comment: Ok can you try: `phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT|INFO_VARIABLES);` in your `phpinfo.php` instead to avoid those 2 additional http requests.

Comment: Its gone because `phpinfo()` otherwise tries to send 2 separate PHP requests for `a PHP logo` and `a Zend logo`.